# Stringstream not extracting after clearing input buffer

Tags: c++, buffer, stringstream

I'm having trouble with stringstream. So I am getting tokens from a csv file and assigning them to some variables but I am clearing stringstream sv after I read every token and after the very first token it stops working and I am not sure why. The commented line, 'stops working here', is where it stops correctly extracting. In visual studio it says sv is '0x000' even after insert operation. I even have another loop in my code that clears it once and does insertion again and that works.

```
int reviewid;
    int userid;
    int rating;
    string reviewDate;
    getline(reviewReader, dummyLine); // skip first line of input
    while (getline(reviewReader, input)) {
        stringstream ss, sv; // sv used for type conversions
        // using delimeter of commas

        // order of input in the file is [ movieid, moviename, pubyear]
        // , first toiken is movieid, second token will be moviename
        // third token will  be pubyear
        ss << input; // take in line of input
        getline(ss, token, ','); // first token
        sv << token; // convert toiken to int
        sv >> reviewid;
        getline(ss, token, ','); // 
        sv.str("");
        sv << token; // STOPS WORKING HERE
        sv >> movieid;
        sv.str(""); // clear buffer
        getline(ss, token, ',');
        sv << token;
        sv >> userid;
        sv.str("");
        getline(ss, token, ',');
        sv << token;
        sv >> rating;
        sv.str("");
        getline(ss, token, ',');
        sv << token;
        sv >> reviewDate;
        sv.str("");  

        Review r = Review(reviewid, movieid, userid, rating, reviewDate); // make review object
        reviews.push_back(r); // add it to vector of reviews
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`str("")` does not change the state of your stream.
i.e. if the stream was in eof state before `str("")` it will still be in the same state after `str("")`.
In order to clear the state please use `clear();`

```
sv.str("");
sv.clear();
```